# Should I use ".html" or "#" when making a navigation bar?

Tags: html

I am trying to make a website and starting off with a navigation bar.
What is the difference between using:

[image: #Home vs Home.html]

Both seem to work the same way as far as I can see but most tutorials use #Home instead of ending with .html

Comment: One redirects to a different URL, the other just jumps to a section in the current page. Of course, if you use Javascript to alter that behaviour, then it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

`#` is used in in-page anchors. Meaning you can go to a specific part of the current page with them. On the other hand, when you link a direct file it opens that specific page.

Answer (score 2):

**#HTML** in href is used to navigate to a specific part of the same file. The octothorp in front of the **HTML** name denotes that it is an ID selector. so you must have an element with an ID of **HTML** to access it. On the other hand, href can also be used to route the user to different URLs and different pages which you have written. For example, you might have a **login.html** page you can redirect the user with **./login.html** in the href.

Answer (score -1):

Well for me `Home.html` shows an error so yep. Plus so far I have never used `Home.html` as an `href`. You use `id's` in `href` to enable jumping in your webpage and using `#Home` will do the job perfectly. I don't know about the difference as I have never seen `Home.html` as a `href`.
For context, it shows me this

[image: Result]

So ill suggest you to only use the normal `href` pattern which starts with "`#`".